# What is the meaning of this in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

Hello Can anyone tell what is the meaning of this validation ? specially the '*'.

```
$rules = [
          'user.*.username' => 'required|distinct',

];
$message = [
          'user.*.username.required' => 'Username name is required.'
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $message);
```

Comment: It's for validation arrays. You can read more about it [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: '*' is for each array value.`'user.*.username' => 'required|distinct',` this will check each username in users array is required and distinct

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the `*` means all. What do I mean by all?

In the request an array of user is coming, for example:

```
$user = [
  [
    'username' => 'user1',
    //... other fields
  ],
  [
    'username' => 'user2',
    //... other fields
  ],
  //... so on
];
```

So,

`'user.*.username' => 'required|distinct',`

means, `username` of **all** users of that user array(in the request) is required and distinct. You can consider this as a smart and dynamic way of doing the following:

```
'user.0.username' => 'required|distinct',
'user.1.username' => 'required|distinct',
//... so on
```

Answer (score 0):

$this is the current class reference that uses the trait ValidatesRequests in which validate() is present.
Ref. Laravel 5.1
In laravel 5.6 you dont need $this.